# How do I remove/auto delete reactions from a message?

Tags: python, events, discord, discord.py

I am in the process of creating a question bot. Here the bot asks different questions and also gives different ways to respond. I would like to keep this possibility. But I need an event, which removes the reactions under this message, after a user has submitted it. I haven't really found anything unfortunately, but would do something with a `raw_reaction` event, would I be right and how would that need to look? I also think that I would also need to define all the code to get the reactions of the message, is this so?
My code so far:

```py
    @commands.command()
    async def trivia_q(self, ctx):
        await ctx.send("Test, check your DMs")

        def check(m):
            return ctx.author == m.author and isinstance(m.channel, discord.DMChannel)

        e = discord.Embed(color=discord.Color.gold())
        e.title = "New question, new luck."
        e.description = "**When was Steve Jobs born?**"
        e.add_field(name="1️⃣", value="02/24/1955", inline=False)
        e.add_field(name="2️⃣", value="03/24/1955", inline=False)
        e.add_field(name="3️⃣", value="02/24/1965", inline=False)
        e.set_footer(text="You have x-x to answer this question.", icon_url=self.bot.user.avatar_url)
        e.timestamp = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
        question = await ctx.send(embed=e)
        await question.add_reaction("1️⃣")
        await question.add_reaction("2️⃣")
        await question.add_reaction("3️⃣")
        try:
            question = await self.bot.wait_for('reaction_add', timeout=60.0, check=check)
        except asyncio.TimeoutError:
            await ctx.author.send("You took to long to react.")
            return
        await asyncio.sleep(10)
        e2 = discord.Embed(color=discord.Color.gold())
        e2.title = "New question, new luck."
        e2.description = "Test1"
        e2.add_field(name="1️⃣", value="02/24/1955")
        e2.add_field(name="2️⃣", value="03/24/1955")
        e2.add_field(name="3️⃣", value="02/24/1965")
        e2.set_footer(text="You have x-x to answer this question.")
        e2.timestamp = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
        await question.edit(embed=e2)
        await question.add_reaction("1️⃣")
        await question.add_reaction("2️⃣")
        await question.add_reaction("3️⃣")
```

Edit: I guess this will be a DM only command, not sure yet - Maybe makes it easier.

The error code I get is now:

```py
TypeError: check() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

How would I continue?

Comment: To answer your comment below, you can use `wait_for("reaction_add", ...)` This actually works for any built-in event

Comment: @effprime I am actually looking for a function that just removes the reaction from a user, not a function that removes also the bot reactions itself. I guess I have to work with an event as `await reaction.remove(user)` just works for one reaction.

Comment: You can loop through a message's reactions and remove them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove all reactions from a message at once:

```
question = await ctx.send(embed=e)
await question.clear_reactions()
```

If you are trying to do this after a user has responded, use the `await bot.wait_for("message", check=some_check_function)`

See: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.wait_for

Comment: Thanks for the help. Do you think this check is needed in a DM command? For a public thing a check would be good, yes, as I wait for the reaction and then directly remove it.

Comment: `wait_for` will wait for any message that the bot sees, including in other channels. So you may want to write logic in your check function that gets the channel the message is from, and see if it is a DMChannel type (`isinstance(channel, discord.DMChannel)`)

Comment: Would check it with `def check(m):
return ctx.author == m.author and isinstance(m.channel, discord.DMChannel)`

Comment: There is no `ctx` in your local scope, so it looks like you're checking if the author who sent the original command is the same author who sent the new message. If that's the case, then yes!

Comment: What would be the case if I just want to check reaction? How would the check look like? I always get `check() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given` as an error code

Comment: I would make a new StackOverflow question or maybe edit your existing one with new code.

Comment: Edited my question to see my new steps I did.